# run automatically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

Is it possible to run a part of code automatically in asp.net or mvc at special time. for example send mail to a group pf users exactly at 8 in the morning ( only by server and not by user)

Answer (score 1):

No, but there are a few ways you could do it:

- [Quartz.net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/features.html)
- A powershell script (which calls into the code you want to run) and job scheduler
- A console application (which exposes and calls the code you want to run) and job scheduler

Comment: thanks for your answer . i used it . it works on localhost without any problem but in server it does not.only works when an user send request to the server